# SQL Datasource Nulling Update Parameter values?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, datasource

I have a data source that has the update statement:

```
UpdateCommand="Update Apps Set AppDate = Convert(Datetime,@AppDate,103), Slot = @Slot,
               Duration = @Duration, TPMId = @TPMId, AppTypeId = @AppTypeId,
               AppStatusId = @AppStatusId, Location = @Location,
               OtherLocation = @OtherLocation, Comments = @Comments
               where AppId = @AppId;
               update Profile Set PrimaryContact = @PrimaryContact,
               ContactTel = @ContactTel, ContactMob = @ContactMob,
               ContactEmail = @ContactEmail where CompanyID = @CompanyID"
```

and my update parameters are set as such:

```
<UpdateParameters>

    <asp:Parameter Name="AppDate" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Slot" />
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Duration"  ControlID="HFDuration" />  
    <asp:Parameter Name="TPMId" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="AppTypeId" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="AppStatusId" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Location" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="OtherLocation" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Comments" />
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="AppId" QueryStringField="AppID" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="PrimaryContact" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ContactTel" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ContactMob" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ContactEmail" />
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="CompanyID" QueryStringField="CompanyID" />

</UpdateParameters>
```

I have all the controls on the form view set for two way binding and are sitting with bind and not eval eg (<

```
asp:TextBox ID="LocationTB" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Location") %>' 
                                           TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

)

yet when it comes to running the update query the only values that actually get pulled through are the query string and control parameters the rest of the fields all get a null value.

I have had multiple form views with more than one update query before so I know this is not likely to be the issue.

Anyone have any suggestions as to why my datasource update is leaving my table full of nulls?

Comment: Maybe there's some technique I'm not aware of that you are trying to apply, but I don't see any reason why you should expect values to be populated for parameters that are NOT control parameters, and where you haven't explicitly populated them.  Why don't you make them all Control Parameters?

Comment: if you are binding from the formview the controls should (and in the other 100 Datasources I have set up do) just pull the values from the controls that the values are bound to. this is literally the first time this has not happened automatically